# 400 Bad request when creating a new text post. Tumblr API

Tags: java, c#, api, tumblr

I got an error when trying to create a new post with Tumblr API

```
   {"meta":{"status":400,"msg":"Bad Request"},"response":{"errors":["Post cannot be empty."]}}
```

Here is my request:

```
   POST https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/someblog.tumblr.com/post          
   HTTP/1.1
   User-Agent: BADNESS
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   Authorization: OAuth         
   oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",         
   oauth_nonce="1c5uy752", oauth_signature="Qq9OE7wGE6Ml2ovbu7qzm0orjo8%3D", 
   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1456062098",       
   oauth_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
   oauth_verifier="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",  
   oauth_version="1.0"
   Host: api.tumblr.com
   Content-Length: 36
   Expect: 100-continue

   body%3dok%26title%3dok%26type%3dtext
```

I can delete a post, so i'm pretty sure the header is correct, but not sure about post body.

If the POST body like:

```
body=ok&title=ok&type=text
```

I got

```
401 Unauthorized
```

Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you update question with code which is responsible for sending request ?

Comment: @IMU Basically, this code generate the header above... I've tested this, i'm sure that the header is correct but not sure about params (POST body)... Can you find any mistake in the header?

Comment: @IMU And it'd be great to have these details made plain, and not in example code, so that anybody can look at it without having to know 
programming language X or Y or Z.